# Multer error cannot upload file with size above 50kb

Tags: node.js, express

I'm having an issue with multer since I'm using socket.io(I'm not sure but after I use this my multer middleware did not work properly). Here is my code for more information

```
const maxSize = 1024 * 1024 * 2

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (_req, _file, cb) {
    cb(null, path.join(process.cwd(), 'assets', 'pictures'))
  },
  filename: function (_req, file, cb) {
    const ext = file.originalname.split('.')[1]
    const date = new Date()
    cb(null, `${date.getTime()}.${ext}`)
  }
})

const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
  limits: { fileSize: maxSize }
}).single('picture')

const uploadFilter = (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req, 'test mmulter first')
  upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err instanceof multer.MulterError) {
      return response(res, false, err.message, 400)
    } else if (err) {
      return response(res, false, err.message, 500)
    }
    // console.log(req, 'test multer second')
    next()
  })
}
```

So when I try to upload a file under 50kb the upload works perfectly, but when I try to put a file with a size of more than 50kb it will keep hanging, no return any response even it no returns an error, so when this error happens the console.log() and next() inside upload not called. The weird thing is the file indeed saved to my local folder (either 50kb or greater) but when it came to the file with size above 50kb it will cropped.
like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpfnH.png)

Comment: Additional information: I try to save the file to my DB so when the file size is above 50kb it will not be saved

Comment: one more information: the picture above that is being cropped is a png file, for jpg, jpeg, etc, it works normal (save to the local folder), but yeah it is still got the same error (no file save to the DB)